# NullPointerException when calling new Chapter(int) in iText 5.4.4

Tags: java, itext

I tried to add section into a chapter after this chapter is added into document.
Here is my code:

```
Chapter chapter = new Chapter("chapter1", 1);
chapter.addSection("section1");
document.add(chapter);

chapter = new Chapter(1);
chapter.addSection("section2");
document.add(chapter);
```

This works with version 5.0.4 (book version), but it failed with the latest 5.4.4. I got NullPointerException in line "chapter = new Chapter(1);".

Here is the error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.itextpdf.text.Section.<init>(Section.java:176)
at com.itextpdf.text.Chapter.<init>(Chapter.java:82)
at mihoTest.MihoTest03.main(MihoTest03.java:36)
```

Jus wonde what's the correct way to call new Chapter(int).

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If I'd had to guess, I'd guess that a problem was introduced when adding support for Tagged PDF. I've made an internal ticket on the iText support system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've discovered a bug. It has been fixed in the SVN repository: https://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/6074/

The problem occurs when you create a `Chapter` without a title.

Comment: Thank you Bruno. Your book is great. If you can add an example of creating TOC with page number into your next edition, that will be perfect.